# Prolog | Get a list in which elements are calculated with other list and a constant value

Tags: prolog

I have a homework about a films and series distributor enterprise. I've to make an predicate in which i will pass a Value and Month and it will return a sort list with the contract number whose total amount to pay for Month it should be bigger than Value.

I drop the formulas for total amount below

```
Total amount = minimum amount + royalty amount
Royalty amount = (monthly net - minimum amount)*royalty percent
Monthly net = monthly income - distribution spending - cost percent
Cost percent = (monthly net - minimum amount)*cost percent
```

I made predicates for royalty amount and monthly net, the code is this:

```
contract('A255', 'Distributor A', 'CSI Las Vegas', '3M3520', '2', ['DVD', 'Streaming'], 30.000).
contract('A566', 'Distributor B', 'Ghost Hunters', '1Q2010', 1, ['Cinema'], 50.000).
contract('A897', 'Distributor A', 'Sherlock Holmes', '1M2020', 2, ['DVD', 'BlueRay', 'TVP', 'Streaming'], 75.000).
contract('A123', 'Distributor C', 'Lion King', '2Q3015', 1, ['DVD', 'BlueRay', 'TVP', 'Streaming'], 65.000).
contract('A453', 'Distributor B', 'La odisea de los giles', '1M2020', 1, ['Cinema'], 35.000).
contract('A690', 'Distributor C', 'El Robo del Siglo', '1Q2010', 1, ['Cinema'], 45.000).

%Contract number, income date(day, month, year), income amount, spendings amount, country.
monthlyIncomes('A123', date(15, 03, 2020), 45000, 17500, 1).
monthlyIncomes('A123', date(31, 03, 2020), 20000, 16500, 1).
monthlyIncomes('A123', date(30, 06, 2020), 50000, 22500, 3).
monthlyIncomes('A453', date(12, 06, 2020), 30000, 15000, 2).
monthlyIncomes('A453', date(28, 06, 2020), 25000, 15000, 2).
monthlyIncomes('A690', date(02, 02, 2020), 12000, 13500, 3).
monthlyIncomes('A690', date(29, 02, 2020), 95500, 13500, 3).
monthlyIncomes('A690', date(31, 03, 2020), 80000, 12500, 1).
monthlyIncomes('A897', date(16, 03, 2020), 40000, 17000, 2).
monthlyIncomes('A897', date(31, 03, 2020), 15000, 17000, 2).
monthlyIncomes('A897', date(02, 29, 2020), 50000, 17000, 1).
monthlyIncomes('A566', date(30, 04, 2020), 50000, 16500, 3).
monthlyIncomes('A255', date(10, 04, 2020), 72000, 14500, 3).
monthlyIncomes('A255', date(30, 04, 2020), 90000, 14500, 3).
monthlyIncomes('A540', date(12, 06, 2020), 30000, 10800, 2).
monthlyIncomes('A540', date(30, 06, 2020), 30800, 10700, 2).
monthlyIncomes('A540', date(31, 07, 2020), 30500, 10600, 1).
monthlyIncomes('A120', date(31, 07, 2020), 25500, 23400, 1).
monthlyIncomes('A234', date(15, 05, 2020), 75600, 12800, 1).
monthlyIncomes('A234', date(31, 05, 2020), 75600, 12800, 1).

%Royalty, name, percentage to pay, cost percentage, country.
royalties('1Q2010', 'Royalty 1', 0.20, 0.10, 1).
royalties('1M2020', 'Royalty 2', 0.20, 0.20, 2).
royalties('2Q3015', 'Royalty 3', 0.30, 0.15, 1).
royalties('2M2515', 'Royalty 4', 0.25, 0.15, 2).
royalties('3M3520', 'Royalty 5', 0.35, 0.20, 3).

%id, name
product_type(1, 'Film').
product_type(2, 'Serie').

country(1, 'Argentina').
country(2, 'New Zeland').
country(3, 'Albania').

get_net_value(Contract, Month, Net) :-  
    findall(Incomes, monthlyIncomes(Contract, date(_, Month, _), Incomes, _, _), Incomes),                  
    findall(Spendings, monthlyIncomes(Contract, date(_, Month, _), _, Spendings, _), Spendings), 
    sumlist(Incomes, SumIncomes), sumlist(Spendings, SumSpendings), 
    Net1 is SumIncomes - SumSpendings,
    contract(Contract, _, _, Royalty, _, _, MinimumAmount), royalties(Royalty, _, _, PctCost, _),
    Net is Net1 - Net1*PctCost.

royalty_amount(Contract, Month, RoyaltyAmount) :-
    get_net_value(Contract, Month, Net),
    contract(Contract, _, _, Royalty, _, _, MinimumAmount),
    royalties(Royalty, _, _, PctCost, _),
    RoyaltyAmount is (Net - MinimumAmount)*PctCost.

amount_by_value(Value, Month, Contract) :- 
    findall(Contract, monthlyIncomes(Contract, date(_, Month, _), _, _, _), Contract),
    findall(MinimumAmount, monthlyIncomes(_, date(_, Month, _), MinimumAmount, _, _), MinimumAmount).
```

amount_by_value it's predicate in which i'm having troubles. With the current code I get a list Contracts with the number of contracts and another list MinimumAmount with the minimum amount for calculus of total amount but i don't know how to obtain the royalty amount for each of contracts.
I was try with the line `maplist(royalty_amount, Contract, [Month], Royalties).`. That's the reason of the question title, the constant value is the month and list is Contracts, but this it return a boolean value false. Can someone give me some advice? it will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is all good but it would be even better if you distilled your question and your code to the necessary minimum.

Comment: When Prolog returns false, the predicate cannot be proved. Maybe a problem of logic, but in your case there is a typo in royalty_amount : Mouth --> Month

Comment: The same typo in get_net_value ! Try your codes again, maybe they are OK now.

Comment: Now typo errors are solved, but it keeps giving a false value with maplist predicate

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to help you. You have to read up on the findall/3 predefined predicate. Its uses in both get_net_value/3 and amount_by_value/3 will never succeed.

findall(**Var**, **Goal**, **ListOfVars**).
**Var** is either un single variable (X) or a template (e.g. a list or a functor with one or variables). The single or more variables occur in **Goal**.
Whenever **Goal** succeeds, the current value of **Var** is collected into the **ListOfVars**.

So **ListOfVars** is forcibly a list, it can never be equal to **Var**, as you used in the get_net_value/3 and amount_by_value/3 predicates.

Hope it helps! Or else explain further your problem.